# True values become 1 when a value in pandas column is changing to nan

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I have a dataframe similar to the below example, with a column that contains True or Nan:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'T/F':[True, True, True, True, True]})

Data   T/F
0     1  True
1     2  True
2     3  True
3     4  True
4     5  True
```

I want to try and remove the true from the final row in this dataframe, but when I do all the other Trues become 1:

```
df.loc[df.last_valid_index(), 'T/F'] = np.nan

   Data  T/F
0     1  1.0
1     2  1.0
2     3  1.0
3     4  1.0
4     5  NaN
```

I was wondering if anyone knows why this happens? and any way I can stop it? I'm thinking I might need to change my code to use False instead of nan.

Comment: `True` remains as `True` after running `df.loc[df.last_valid_index(), 'T/F'] = np.nan` in my installation.  My version is the latest version 1.3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `pd.NA` instead:

```
df.loc[df.last_valid_index(), 'T/F'] = pd.NA
```

output of `df`:

```
    Data    T/F
0   1       True
1   2       True
2   3       True
3   4       True
4   5       <NA>
```

**Note:** Since the type of `np.nan` is `float` so that why it is convering boolean `True` to `1.0` and boolean `False` to `0.0`

Also `pd.NA` preserve datatype you can check that by:

```
print(df['T/F'].map(type))

#output of above code:

0                           <class 'bool'>
1                           <class 'bool'>
2                           <class 'bool'>
3                           <class 'bool'>
4    <class 'pandas._libs.missing.NAType'>
Name: T/F, dtype: object
```

Comment: what's the `dtype` now? object?

Comment: @Umar.H it is `bool` and for `pd.NA` it is `'pandas._libs.missing.NAType'`

Comment: This is perfect, thank you :) will accept as soon as I can

Comment: Do you know how you check if a value is `pd.NA` like `math.isnan()`?

Comment: @EmiOB you can use `pd.isna()` or `pd.isnull()` or `df.isna()` or `df.isnull()`

Comment: @EmiOB updated answer added a liitle ,more info....kindly have a look **:)**

Answer (score 1):

One column, one type, when you  set value `np.nan`, program will convert this column to float. In my memory , df.astype() function just process column, not ceil.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that the `T/F` column contains `bool` data and the value you try to assign is of type `numpy.float64`, so the column is being casted to the highest mutual `dtype`, which is `numpy.float64` in this case.

If you would like to contain a mixed values in this column, i.e., both `bool` and `numpy.float64`, you should cast this column to `object` before updating it, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'T/F':[True, True, True, True, True]})
df['T/F'] = df['T/F'].astype('object')
df.loc[df.last_valid_index(), 'T/F'] = np.nan
df
```

**Output:**

```
    Data    T/F
0   1   True
1   2   True
2   3   True
3   4   True
4   5   NaN
```

Note:
Holding mixed values in `pandas.DataFrames` is ussualy not a good practice, as it slows down considerably the performance, so it should be avoided whenever possible.

Cheers